# PHP $this keyword in Inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, this

I know PHP `$this` keyword refer to the ***current*** object, but I want to understand it when we use it in inheritance. For example, when I run below piece of code, it runs for infinte recursion.

```
<?php
class Fruit {
  public function intro() {
    echo "In Fruit-intro"; 
    $this->display();
  }
  public function display() {
      echo "Fruit-display"; 
  }
}

class Strawberry extends Fruit {
  public function display() {
    parent::intro();
  }
}

$strawberry = new Strawberry();
$strawberry->display();
?>
```

So here I was expecting `$this->display` in the Fruit's `intro()` method (line number:5 ) to call Fruit's `display()` method but instead it is calling Strawberry's `display()` method (ie calling to itself). I confirmed it when I put `var_dump($this)` in Fruit's class it shows:-

`object(Strawberry)#1 (0) { }`

Here `$this` refers to the calling object(`Strawberry`) not the current object(`Fruits`).

Can somebody please help me to understand this?
It might be very trivial question to be asked but I want to clear my concepts.
Thanks!

Comment: How can you expect `Fruit::display` to be called when you override the method in the child class `Strawberry::display`?

Comment: `$this` refers to the *current __object__*. There's only one object here, the instance of `Strawberry`. And its `display` method is `Strawberry::display`.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, for commenting, so $this keyword not bound with the Fruit class? we can't use $this keyword to access the properties and method of the Fruit class.(Yes all those properties, methods will be available in the child class). But if we use the `final` keyword to prevent any overridden of the function, then how can i use $this keyword in the parent class to refer that function?

Comment: No, it's not bound to any *class*. `$strawberry->display()` and `$this->display()` do exactly the same thing.